# Como trabalhar corretamente com o request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic, typescript

Preciso mandar uma simples notificação usando onesignal, porém está dando erro no build do web app por conta do import do https, conforme o código eu estou importando da seguinte maneira:

var https = require('https');

Obs: Este exemplo é do site do próprio onesignal, o problema é que não consigo fazer o request de outra forma, assim até funciona, mas na hora do build da erro. Então o que eu preciso basicamente é, descobrir uma outra forma de chamar este https para fazer o request para api do onesignal e resolver o problema. Só preciso disso para fechar este projeto.

```
  notificaAgendamentoCriadoProfissional(){
  var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };

  var https = require('https');
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("Response:");
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};

var message = { 
  app_id: "meu id",
  contents: {"en": "Você recebeu uma nova solicitação. Verifique imediatamente a sua lista de agendamentos"},
  include_player_ids: [this.idOneSignalProfissional]
};

sendNotification(message);
```

}

O erro que estou recebendo é sempre este:

```
[18:23:19]  typescript: ...roAdm/src/pages/criar-agendamento-procedimento/criar-agendamento-procedimento.ts, line: 178 
        Cannot find name 'require'.

L178:   var https = require('https');
```

Comment: Resolvi aqui, consegui remontar a função e fazer o post!

Comment: Diego, considere postar uma resposta mostrando o que estava errado e como você conseguiu resolver.

Comment: Atualizei, e coloquei o exemplo da correção

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está um exemplo de como resolvi esta questão:

```
  notificaAgendamentoCriadoProfissional() {
  let data = {
  app_id: "Seu Id do onesignal",
  contents: { "en": "Você recebeu uma nova solicitação. Verifique imediatamente a sua lista de agendamentos" },
  include_player_ids: ['id do usuário do one signal']
};
let url = 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications';
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
});

this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe((result: any) => {
    console.log('sucesso ao salvar');
    console.log(result);
  },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Comment: Se isso resolveu o seu problema, assim que puder aceite a sua resposta (vêzinho verde).